# My CollapsingToolbarLayout is not changing color once it is collapsed

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout and a viewflipper inside of it to auto change the images. My problem is when the user scrolls up or once it is collapsed , my app bar is showing the Viewflipper images, i dont want to do that i want my toolbar must get the original color once it collapsed
[This is what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbXEe.jpg), [second image once it is collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuZYs.jpg)

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/srinivasflipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ViewFlipper>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Switch `ToolBar` and `Flipper` Since `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is a `FrameLayout` .

Comment: how about setting height of view flipper to wrap_content?

Comment: And why are you using toolbar? i don't think so it save any purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` inside the viewfliper it is required for the desired effect .

[Collapsing Toolbars](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

> you can use app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" (and optionally app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" to set the parallax multiplier) to implement parallax scrolling (say of a sibling ImageView within the CollapsingToolbarLayout). This use case pairs nicely with the app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary" attribute for CollapsingToolbarLayout, adding a full bleed scrim when the view is collapsed.

**Note :**

Also since collapsing toolbar extends framelayout , you need to place the toolbar below viewflipper.